# WMI win32_physicalmedia code is crashing in windows 8.1

Tags: wmi, wmi-query, wmi-service

Hello I'm using Visual C++ 2010.

I am trying to extract hardware details using wmi and everything is working fine but when i tested the application in windows 8.1 the application crashes and it turned out to be from the win32_physicalmedia code.

Here is the code :

```
pSvc->ExecQuery(
    bstr_t("WQL"), 
    bstr_t("SELECT SerialNumber FROM Win32_PhysicalMedia"),
    WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY | WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY, 
    NULL,
    &pEnumerator);

 IWbemClassObject *pclsObjjj;
ULONG uReturnnn = 0;

while (pEnumerator)
{
    HRESULT hr = pEnumerator->Next(WBEM_INFINITE, 1, 
        &pclsObjjj, &uReturnnn);

    if(0 == uReturnnn)
    {
        break;
    }

    VARIANT vtProp;
```

It's working fine on windows xp and 7 but on windows 8.1 when it reaches to to get this one it crashes and gives dont send.

Any advice ?

Comment: Try capturing the result of the `ExecQuery` method in order to get any idea about the error.

Comment: Okay thank you i'll try this when i get home and give my feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay guys i guess i got it.It was because i didnt add "return 0;" at the end !!!!!

On windows xp and 7 it's working fine but if it's running on windows 8 it crashes ..

It's weird i dunno why but problem is solved anyway xD